# Bootstrap Modal text is aligned to the right

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog, bootstrap-modal, bootstrap-5

I just made a modal where i have put a sign up form and every text i've put in it including labels are aligned to the right by default... Is there any solution to this?

```
 <div class="modal fade" id="signUp">
                <div class="modal-dialog">
                    <div class="modal-content">
                        <div class="modal-header bg-light"><h1 class="text-center">Create an Account<h1></div>
                        <div class="modal-body">
                            <p clasS="lead">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Neque minima aliquid adipisci ratione ex recusandae at placeat eaque, temporibus rerum sunt mollitia eius eligendi corrupti? Quo esse possimus neque doloribus.</p>
                            <form action="" method="POST" class="w-75 m-auto">
                                <div class="form-row">
                                    <div class="form-group col-6">
                                        <label for="firstName" class="text-right">First Name</label>
                                        <input type="text" name="firstName" class="form-control">
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group col-6">
                                        <label for="lastName" class="form-label">Last Name</label>
                                        <input type="text" name="lastName" class="form-control">
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group"><label for="email" class="form-label">Email</label><input type="email" name="email" class="form-control"></div>
                                <div class="form-group"><label for="text" class="form-label">Username</label><input type="user" name="user" class="form-control"><small class="form-text">Must be between 8-20 characters long</small></div>
                                <div class="form-group"><label for="password" class="form-label">Password</label><input type="password" name="password" class="form-control"><small class="form-text">Must include atleast one special character and one uppercase letter</small></div>
                                <div class="form-group"><label for="confirmPass" class="form-label">Confirm Password</label><input type="password" name="confirmPass" class="form-control"></div>
                            </form>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-footer bg-light">
                            <div class="d-flex justify-content-end"><input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Create account">&nbsp<input type="reset" class="btn btn-danger" value="Cancel">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Maybe remove the "m-auto" from the form classes?

```
<form action="" method="POST" class="w-75">
```

If you want it full width, you should also remove the "w-75".

```
<form action="" method="POST">
```